hasAuthority("ADMIN") has no effect in multiple SecurityFilterChain
I have two SecurityFilterChain configurations: one for the key filter and another for the JWT filter. I want to apply each filter to separate sets of APIs.
the code :
@Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain apiKeyFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/clients/**")).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/auth/**")).permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/**")).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(apiKeyAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    public SecurityFilterChain jwtFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/notification/**")).hasAuthority("ADMIN")
                        .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/auth/**")).permitAll()

                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(sess -> sess.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

//In ApiKeyAuthFilter ....
private static final List<String> EXCLUDED_PATHS = Arrays.asList(
            "/auth",
            "/admin",
            "/clients"
   
    );
    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
        String path = request.getServletPath();
        for (String excludedPath : EXCLUDED_PATHS) {
            if (path.startsWith(excludedPath)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

After some effort, the code works well. However, the hasAuthority("ADMIN") condition has no effect unless I delete the first SecurityFilterChain.  Coming from a .NET background, I'm still a bit confused with Java
Did I miss something?

When you have two SecurityFilterChains, they will be processed in priority order. In your case the first will be processed before the second and therefore if the request corresponds to an AntPathRequestMatcher, the second filter will not be executed. To resolve this you have two solutions:

Either change the order
Or do it in such a way that the query will not match one of the urls present in the first filter

Hope this will help you!

if I remove ".requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/**")).permitAll()" from the first filter , I get "Unauthorized" response for ""localhost:8080/admin/notification/test"" even  I provide correct token. What about EXCLUDED_PATHS  ,
Isn't the request "http://localhost:8080/admin/notification/test" supposed to exceed the first filter?

Have you tried reversing the order of the filters?
